# Libgdx: Scoring points basic

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to code a score system which increments whenever collision occurs between enemy and player. I initialize my score to 100 and will be incremented once collision is detected, which means the the old score will be 100 and the new one will be 101. but what happen is that my old score is 0 while my new score is 100. can someone help me debut my code. thank you.

here is my code:

[code is in bpaste](http://www.bpaste.net/show/Y0QkJqpvIwnI2fF2jVjo/)

Answer (score 0):

When you call getscore() the first time, it hasn't been initialized yet, so it returns 0.

What your scoreIncrement() method does is to add 100 to tempScore, which is then added to Score (which is now 100).

If I understood your intentions correctly, you could use something like this:

```
//Initialize score to 100
private int score = 100;

//Method for incrementing score by 1
public void scoreIncrement() {
    score++;
}

//score getter
public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
```